# Less interrupting in less

Tags: less, sigint

I often pipe program output to less, e.g.

```
produce_output | less
```

This works great, until `produce_output` produces large amounts of output.  If I search for some text that is deep into the file, less reports

```
Calculating line numbers... (interrupt to abort)
```

If I interrupt with Control+C, it also kills `produce_output`, which stops it from producing further output.  Is there any way to send the interrupt to less, so that `produce_output` keeps running?

I know that I could use `kill -INT less_process`, but I think there must be a better solution.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to exit “less” follow mode without stopping other processes in pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197199/5355)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally all processes in a pipeline run in the same *process group*, causing all of them to receive the signal. You can use `setsid foo | less` to run `foo` in a different pgrp.

Comment: It light of the problem raised by OP it seems that decision to use CTRL+C as a way to interrupt less is very unfortunate. Do you know why this specific signal was chosen? Would some other signal be less problematic?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: What other signal would you suggest? There aren't many that have dedicated keyboard shortcuts, only SIGINT (Ctrl-C) and SIGQUIT (Ctrl-\\), and the latter is meant to exit the program immediately, not merely interrupt. The rest are only available via `kill`.

Comment: It seems that the problem is caused by using signal to interrupt less. Instead, if it were some *normal* key/shortcut we wouldn't have the problem in the first place. However I guess the need for a signal comes from the fact that process can't use `select` to wait for input both from a file/pipe and terminal at the same time.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: It can, that's how the `F` (follow) mode works. Pipes and ttys are pollable the same way.

Comment: Why do you think that's the way follow mode works? I think the flow of events is that shell gets CTRL+C and sends SIGINT signal to less which gets this signal asynchronously without *listening* to keyboard/terminal.

Comment: Note that setsid(1) (setsid(2) syscall as a standalone command) is a Linux-ism. Fortunately, the code is simple, portable to other OSes that have the syscall, and in the public domain, so the command ought to be available at your nearest package manager (either as its own package or as part of a util-linux package; yes, even on non-Linux)

Answer (score 10):

You can disable line numbers with the

```
   -n or --line-numbers
```

option.

```
produce_output | less -n
```

Comment: -1: may solve OP's instigating problem, but does nothing to answer OP's actual question (i.e., interrupting a process).

Comment: Sorry but starting less with a feature that is not wanted and then try to send a signal to disable a feature you can disable with a switch is a workaround and not a solution. Of course @grawity solution is nice (and I up voted it) but come on: starting the first process in another group to be able to send a signal to interrupt a task (line counting) that is not needed is really a little bit too much work.

Comment: This is a fair solution to the problem I posed in my question.  However, interrupts stop more than just the line counting in less -- for instance, they will interrupt a long search too.  So, @grawity's solution is preferred, since it would cover any use of interrupts in less.  My bad for not addressing this more clearly in the question!

Comment: @EdMcMan Sure I also up voted gravity's solution and I happy to learn something new that can always be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just do this:

```
less +F -f <(produce_output)
```

Comment: Simple solution and works fine! The `-f` flag is important to read from the temporary pipe created.

Answer (score 0):

In working with large amounts of output, I've found it very helpful to send the output to a file and use `tail -f` or `less +F` to watch, e.g.:

```
produce_output > out 2>&1 & less +F out
```

The `2>&1` syntax makes sure that both stdout and stderr go to `out`---remove that if you only want stdout going to the file.  This way, you can inspect the output in various ways (even from a different machine) without having to mess with the program producing the output.

Note that `2>&1` may be bash-specific (I'm not sure).  Be sure that you have sufficient disk space for the output file :-)

Comment: Tail will just show you the file, Ed specified that he is using less interactively (e.g., he has to search in the file)

Comment: `2>&1` is POSIX, bare `>&` is a bashism.

Comment: FWIW, 2>&1 also works on Windows XP, 7, 2008, etc.

Comment: @Matteo: yes, I should have used `less +F` in my example; I just updated my answer.

Comment: `less +F` does not disable line counting, if the file is huge this will take time in any case. And it also has the same problem as originally posted: it does not allow to search on the fly you have to press ctrl+c to tell less to stop following the file (`Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)`). If you want to search you have to press ctrl+c, search and then re-enable the follow mode.

Comment: @Matteo: Line counting is not the same issue with `less +F` (since `less +F` processes the data as it is generated).  The example I gave does **not** have the same problem as originally posted: ctrl+c will not interrupt `process_output`.  If one doesn't care for the 'follow' functionality, one can run `produce_output > out 2>&1`, then `less out`.  A problem with `produce_output | less` is that if anything breaks the pipe (e.g. accidentally hitting 'q' from `less`), then `produce_output` will die (without special SIGPIPE handling).

Comment: @jrennie The original problem is that the user had to interrupt the line counting since it was not needed ad was making search slow (the user had to wait). `less +F` will also count lines and according to the manual it will also make several operations slower. Using `less out` as in your last comment will solve the `control-C` problem but why start less with line counting and then interrupt it? You can just start less without line counting and you are done.