# Ctrl+c in a sub process is killing a nohup'ed process earlier in the script

Tags: linux, bash, less, nohup

I didn't know whether this belonged on SO (as it is a coding bug) but thought you guys would be more knowledgeable regarding the subtleties of the software used (so maybe even U&L could be considered).

Here's the minimal code script (see edits for full script, there's a reason I'm doing it this way);

```sh
#/bin/bash
nohup {SERVERCOMMAND} > currentOutput.log 2>&1 &

less +F currentOutput.log
```

What it tries to do is run a server in the background, which outputs to a log file.
Then I `follow` that log file using `less +F`. As you do, to exit this you must hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> before you can hit <kbd>Q</kbd>.

What happens is, when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> inside the `less` command (to stop `tailing`) it somehow kills the server started with `nohup` at the top! Nothing else is affected. I can <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to start tailing the log again (which gets no new info since the server is killed) and if I hit <kbd>Q</kbd> the rest of the script executes normally.

Do you know why this happens? How to avoid it/something else I should be using?

---

P.S.
The server program may be listening for a `^C`, which may be the issue; is there something I can do to stop that? Like, when I just run `{SERVERCOMMAND}` on its own (in a blocking manner), I can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, which doesn't immediately kill it; it prints `Received ^C signal, shutting down` (and then kills itself). This is what's happening when I `^C` in `less` (A final `Received ^C signal, shutting down` is written to the log).

---

P.P.S
I've been trying a number of things (none worked);

- trying to disconnect the stdin from the script by changing

  ```
  nohup {SERVERCOMMAND} > currentOutput.log 2>&1 &
  to
  nohup echo '' | {SERVERCOMMAND} > currentOutput.log 2>&1 &
  or
  nohup cat /dev/null/ | {SERVERCOMMAND} > currentOutput.log 2>&1 &
  ```
- using `stty intr ^G` to replace the interrupt command, but then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> did exactly what `^C` was doing anyway (so this may be an issue with my terminal emulator instead; `konsole`)
- placing the `nohup` &/or the `less` line in parentheses (to make it a subshell)
- running the script in `xterm` instead of `konsole`

Comment: Someone may have [come across](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ignore-disable-ctrl-c-sigint-in-a-shell-script-780188/) my issue; `I think it is due to the handling within the database software, not on the shell`. How would a program do this? How, then, might I stop it?

Comment: `nohup` prevents the process from receiving `SIGHUP` signal whereas CTRL+C sends `SIGINT` signal. That's why `nohup` doesn't have the effect you expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was right in thinking that it was `SIGINT` being sent to all processes when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, but I was silly in thinking that making another process would bring it outside the `process group` (see my attempts in the `P.P.S.`).

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/422428/less-interrupting-in-less) is, not only the exact use case, but the correct solution.

Because of how my script was structured the answer there didn't fit verbatim, this is the script now;

```
#/bin/bash

setsid {SERVERCOMMAND} > currentOutput.log 2>&1 &
less +F currentOutput.log
```

The server continues to output to the log file after I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in `less`.

Thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *disown*?

```
  disown -h %1
```

or whatever your job is; *disown* is a shell built-in, its [man page](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_79.html) states:

> disown
>
> disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If the `-h' option is given, the job is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If jobspec is not present, and neither the`-a' nor `-r' option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec is supplied, the`-a' option means to remove or mark all jobs; the `-r' option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs.

**EDIT**

Funny thing, your construction works on my Arch Linux:

```
 $ cat testm
  #!/bin/sh

  nohup /home/mario/temp/waste & 

  less +F out.log

 $ cat waste
  #!/bin/sh

  while [ 1 ]; do
    find / -print 2>1 1> out.log
  done
  $ ./testm
   nohup: appending output to ‘nohup.out’
  $ ps ax | grep waste
    19090 pts/2    S      0:00 /bin/sh /home/mario/temp/waste
    19124 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep waste]
  $
```

Before the *ps* command, I had to scroll the out.log file, then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, then <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to apply it. I tried placing the `nohup` line in a function which `disowns` itself, but that should be the same as `nohup`. I don't think this is a `SIGHUP` issue, as when I remove the `less` line, the script concludes with the server still running

Comment: @Hashbrown pls see my edit

Comment: Yeah I did a test as well, with a simple bash script being called instead of {SERVER} executable. And nohup just worked fine. See my comment on the question. I think it is purposefully listening somehow. Since its a propriety (and not well known) server I can't even say what it is so someone can go "oh its doing X, you need to do Y"